# Update iOS app that has status:developer removed from sale

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Last week I made one iOS app on the App Store private (developer removed from sale status) and it doesn't show up in the App Store anymore.

My question is, is it possible to still upgrade the app which is in the private status and let the current user who has the app installed on their devices upgrade the app through the App Store?

Comment: AFAIK, You can do it on TestFlight with the invited people (via email). Since your app was removed from AppStore, users will no longer see it and can't update as well.

Comment: but like Android, I thought I still can update the app even after it has been private.

Comment: It's different. Users are allowed to update if there is a new version on the AppStore, however, `remove from sale` means it's not available on the AppStore anymore.

Comment: There is a private option, to customize your app for Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager. You can take a look at AppStoreConnect -> your app -> Pricing and Availability -> App Distribution Method. But I don't think it will work.

Comment: I don't want to use the private distribute option, I just want to let the current users to recieve updates if I update the private app

Comment: Sadly this isn't possible. For some reason Apple does not let developers continue to support existing customers while preventing any new customers of an app.

Comment: oh, I got it. So to summarize, Android is possible but iOS doesn't support updating the app after the app being private from App Store right?

Answer (score 0):

Removed from sale, is applied for new users only.
the people who already installed the app will receive updates.

Also: check out [this article](https://getonthestore.com/update-after-removed-from-sale/) it is useful

So As a walk Around:

> Remove the app from sale and leave it hidden until you decide you need to make an update.
> Submit a new version while the app is still removed from sale.
> Release the update so your existing customers can get it.
> Again remove the app from sale

Comment: How can existing users get updates if a developer is not able to submit any updates to an app that has been removed from sale? At most, existing users can update to the last version that was ever made available on the App Store before it was removed from sale.

Comment: @HangarRash see my updated answer